# applet fails to load class from jar

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, applet

Some users are complaining that the applet no longer works, When they view the java console they are greeted with a java.lang.noClassDefFoundError and checking my access log's I see they have downloaded the jar file that contains the class, and then issue a get request for the particular class.

Different users break on different classes.

Some users are fine.

Any ideas what could cause this/fix this.

I have checked to make sure the file is in their java cache, cleared the cache etc. nothing seems to fix them.

If they hit a qa site it breaks as well.

Comment: Have you looked into the Java cache on their desktop to ensure that the correct version was downloaded?  Could this be a Java version problem?  Was the Applet built with a different Java version than previous?

Comment: Yup, i have verified the files are there. and some clients are working.

Comment: there have been no changes since friday.  its the same ear/jar file that was there friday(same md5) all clients are running 1.6.0_03

Comment: Does it always break on classes from the main JAR file?  Does the main JAR file manifest specify a classpath?

Comment: no, can be different jar files, none of the jars specify a classpath

Comment: (ObNote: 1.6.0_13 a.k.a. 6u13 is the only current version of the Sun Java SE 6 JRE that is up to date with security fixes. 6u14 coming soon, but that should not have any further secuirty fixes (probably).)

Comment: It appears that weblogic7 SP7 is corrupting the jars. It appears that if a connection is too slow(modem speeds?) then weblogic will kill the connection.

It is reprodoucable on weblogic7 sp2 but we dont hit it nearly as often (99.9% vs 1%).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jar is getting corrupted in transit, We are looking at getting patches from oracle/bea for the server.

It appears that if a connection is too slow (Modem speeds) that weblogic will signal the end of a transfer by sending a packet with len=0.

The network will signal java saying the download completed successfully and then java fails with a java.lang.noClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Hi, I think I'm encountering a similar problem, can you give me any details on the patches from oracle/bea?

Comment: sorry to take so long...CR196369 and CR317020 I think the issue was that the default timeout got changed from seconds to ms. so the previous sane value of 50 became not so sane.

Answer (score 1):

This can occur if the class itself can be loaded but some dependency of that class cannot be.  Are there external JARs that are dependencies?

Comment: This answer may not apply to this question, but it was the answer to a problem I am having. Thanks @Eddie!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the jar file contains all the necessary classes?  Open it up in your favorite Zip application and double check.  Maybe a recent build of that jar got messed up and doesn't have everything in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have made some updates by your wording. It is highly likely that some users have a previous Jar file cached.

When deploying a new applet version in a live configuration I perform the following:

1. Ensure the page holding the applet is not cached - use [HTTP no-caching techniques](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881). You may want to redeploy from a new page with these headers to ensure that it's not the case.
2. Deploy the jar file from a different URL for each update (I encode the version number in a directory, but you can equally rename the jar file).
3. If applet performs any client server interaction ensure that you check version numbers and report incorrect version to the user.

Even if you follow this the user may still have a problem, ask them to try these one at a time (listed in order they should try):

1. Press refresh on the browser window.
2. Restart all browser windows
3. Uninstall *all* Java VMs found on "Add/Remove programmes" and reinstall latest Java (yes, they must do this at their own risk!)

Comment: nope same jar's no updates. I have made the clients clear their cache and redownload the jars (i love 56k!) and still nothing.

I have gotten them to uninstall all java's, (1.6.0_03) and reinstall. 

Nothing. 

One client found that when he uninstalled, rebooted, reinstalled it worked once.

Comment: (ie resolved class files from the jars) and any time after that the JRE would not load the class file from the jar and would try and obtain it from the server which results in a 404 and then the JRE bombs with a NoClassDefFoundError.

And that only worked on one pc, the rest would always fail.

Comment: load: class com.bankframe.foo.launch.manager.FooApplet.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bankframe.foo.launch.manager.FooApplet.class
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unk

Comment: Caused by: java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed:http://10.103.113.127:7200/applications/com/bankframe/foo/launch/manager/FooApplet/class.class
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getBytes(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)

Comment: at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 ... 7 more
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bankframe.foo.launch.manager.FooApplet.class

Comment: names have been changed from foo to protect the guilty :-)

Comment: I suspect the problem is with your HTML tag. I specify "com.company.Applet" not "com.company.Applet.class" in my code. Which tag do you use, Applet, Object or Embed?

Comment: <OBJECT classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
WIDTH=851  HEIGHT=571 align="left">
      <PARAM NAME=CODEBASE VALUE=./applications >
      <PARAM NAME=ARCHIVE VALUE="framework.jar, foo_ext.jar, foo_gui.jar, foo_int.jar" >

Comment: <PARAM NAME=CODE VALUE = com.bankframe.Foo.launch.manager.FooApplet.class >
      <PARAM NAME="type" VALUE="application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.2_04"><COMMENT> 
      <EMBED type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.2" java_CODE = com.bankframe.foo.launch.manager.FooApplet.class

Comment: ARCHIVE="framework.jar, foo_ext.jar, foo_gui.jar, foo_int.jar" CODEBASE=./applications WIDTH=851  HEIGHT=571 align="left">
        <NOEMBED></COMMENT> </NOEMBED> 
      </EMBED> 
  </OBJECT>

Comment: You should ensure all your parameters are quoted, especially the code.  <PARAM NAME=CODE VALUE = com.bankframe.Foo.launch.manager.FooApplet.class > to <param name="code" value="com.bankframe.Foo.launch.manager.FooApplet.class">

Comment: It's also worth running your HTML through the W3 validator at http://validator.w3.org. Do you know if the failure is browser/OS dependent

Comment: it seems to be intermittent at best...turning the logging to all on the java console yields

java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream  at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)  at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  at

Comment: Possibly a problem with the Jar creation?

Comment: appears weblogic 7sp7 is corrupting the jar files

switching weblogic7sp2 seems to fix it