# Applet class loader cannot find one of the classes in the jar

Tags: java, applet, classloader, noclassdeffounderror

I get the ff. error in Java Console occassionally:

```
Exception in thread "thread applet-my.package.MyApplet-10" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: another/package/SomeClass
    at my.package.MyApplet.init(MyApplet.java:95)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: another.package.SomeClass
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed:https://myserver/mycontext/applets/another/package/SomeClass.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ... 7 more
```

My applet tag is as follows:

```
<applet codebase="../../applets" code="my.package.MyApplet" class="invisible" id="myApplet">
  <param value="value0" name="param0"/>
  ...
  <param value="valueN" name="paramN" />
  <param value="folder/myApplet__0.0.1177.jar,folder/commons-io-1.3.2__0.0.1177.jar,..." name="cache_archive"/>
  <param value="0.0.1177.0,0.0.1177.0,...," name="cache_version"/>
</applet>
```

It is important I stress the word "occasionally".  Sometimes the applet is initialized without a hitch.  This also means that, often, when the browser is restarted, the problem goes away.

I am aware of [applet fails to load class from jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698890/applet-fails-to-load-class-from-jar) and [Applet class loader cannot find a class in the applet's jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872905/applet-class-loader-cannot-find-a-class-in-the-applets-jar) but I think they are not applicable to my case.  SomeClass and MyApplet are in the same jar and the page is being accessed locally.

Comment: I think what happens is that the Java browser plug-in was not able to load the class from myApplet__0.0.1177.jar and so went looking for it in the codebase folder.  The question now is that how is it able to load MyApplet but not SomeClass?

Comment: What version of Java is used on the client side?

Comment: You said that the page is being accessed locally, but in logs I see "myserver". Is this name of your localhost machine?

Also, what browser do you use to test? Internet explorer, firefox?

Comment: 1.6 update 10 is the version of Java used.  The "myserver" in the stack trace above is just an example.  It's not the localhost.  The browser is Firefox.

Comment: The applet element shown above is invalid HTML.  It would be best to check it using a validation service before pondering other reasons it might fail.  And on the 'class="invisible"', don't make the mistake of specifying width or height < 10 or common browser plug-ins might remove the applet without warning.

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed:https://myserver/mycontext/applets/another/package/SomeClass.class
```

This looks like there is a connection issue with retrieving the jar file from the HTTPS server.

I don't know exactly what version of Java are you running, but you can check the reason of the defect pertaining to your problem [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6891332).

If this is not the problem, then make sure that there's enough caching for your JAR file when downloaded else it fails to launch. It's not code issue unfortunately.

**UPDATE** Is your class `SomeClass` accessing any remote server or database by any chance?

The exception clearly shows that there is an `AccessControl` privilege that has been denied.

```
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Bear in mind, that applets are like Flash Objects:

- They are both downloaded and run from the client side.

Only difference is that Applets were designed with lots of access control rules such as, it must not connect to servers hidden behind company DMZ (De-Militarized Zone), etc.

If that's the case, I suggest you find a way to retrieve your data outside applets (try servlet?)

**UPDATE 2** It seems the JVM can't find the trusted certificate to match with your signed jar.

1. Since your jar file is **signed** make sure that the jar file can point your trusted certificate (remember, it must be trusted).
2. More information, check: http://faq.javaranch.com/java/HowCanAnAppletReadFilesOnTheLocalFileSystem AND http://www.developer.com/article.php/3303561

Comment: If it's a connection issue, shouldn't the URL in the exception message be https:// myserver/mycontext/applets/myApplet__0.0.1177.jar instead?  It seems that the plug-in is looking for the class file itself in the codebase.

Comment: SomeClass is not accessing any remote server or database.  It is, however, reading files from the local filesystem.  I've wrapped that in a privileged call.  I've also signed the jars.

I think the Java browser plug-in is doing the privileged access.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far but the problem is still unsolved.  The jar's cert is already permanently trusted and is in both the browser and the Java plug-in's cert stores.

Comment: Which browser, the client browser? Because it seems like the client browser can't access the trusted CERT.

Comment: Yes, the client browser.  How can you tell that the client browser can't access the cert?

Comment: Because the app is loaded by the browser (so it resides on the client, and it's executed from client side) but the Applet can't see the CERT.

Comment: How can you tell that the applet can't see the cert?  Where in the stack trace is this indicated?

Comment: Have you configured htts proxy setting for the applet?

Answer (score 0):

Probably has something to do with http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html.  I.e., one or more of the jars defines/expects a provider.  Investigate when there is time.